# Prolog Flight Paths

Tags: prolog, flightpath

I am working on a homework, and have it pretty much done. Easiest CS homework I've done in recent memory. It's to write a Prolog program to find flight paths between different cities. So

```
oneStop(X,Y)
```

will find if the two cities have one stop between them, and so on for two, three, and four stops, as well as

```
 flightExists(X, Y)
```

which finds if a paths exists in general. They all work great except that the output I get doesn't list out the entire flight path, only whichever    `X/Y` I replace with the variable.  How do I list out all the cities in between?

Comment: this question make me think it's time for you to review earlier homework...

Comment: Add an argument somewhere in one of your predicates that carries the list of places visited when determining the flight. Obviously, it traverses a flight path to determine that there is one. So you just have to build it into a list as you go. Should be just as easy as the rest of it was. :)

Comment: The class is about learning programming language concepts, and we're using a bunch of different 'micro' languages (uSmallTalk uScheme etc.) which they built interpreters for. This is the only Prolog project we're doing, and it's supposed to just be a simple one, especially since "uProlog" is essentially the full thing.

Comment: It's simple to add a list argument, and list processing is fundamental in Prolog.